# The filename in Chinese can not be display in Blender 2.8 when file explore in open

Tags: interface

When I tried to load a video to video sequencer, the file name in Chinese could not be displayed.

Comment: This is a bug, you should report it, so that it will be fixed soon. See https://www.blender.org/support/

Comment: @m.ardito no this is not a bug.

Comment: @joseph, it was a video file, with both name and extension in chinese characters? And did you see other strange characters (like boxes) instead of the expected ones or you didn't see the file item at all?

Comment: it was "fname.mp4", fname is in Chinese and it was shown as boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The default font used for the interface does not contain all characters, Chinese is one of them.

There are two options to solve this in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*)

1. Activate *Translation*  and set language to *Simplified Chinese* or *Traditional Chinese*. It may also work with *Automatic* depending on your OS language configurations.
2. Choose a different *Interface Font* for the interface which includes Chinese characters.

I think the first option is likely the best for your problem. Optionally you can also activate the checkmark next to *Interface* in the translation options to switch the entire interface to Chinese.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: I activated the checkmark next to Interface in the translation options and I was able to see the Chinese characters. Thanks.

Comment: @joseph If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted, by ticking the checkmark on the top left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested in another answer, the issue could be solved just by turning on the interface "translation" feature. On my linux mint I created a txt file with some random chinese characters, and it was displayed good on my desktop and in text editor.

But when I tried to load it in Blender 2.80, all I could see was a bunch of boxes instead of the chinese characters.

[image]

it was sufficient to enable "translation", keeping it "Automatic" and the UI immediately shown the chinese characters, with no other option enabled, and no other font loaded. I guess why this is not a default option.

[image]

@joseph, you could even save your preferences as default after setting this - although on my fresh 2.80 I discovered to have "auto save preferences" enabled...

[image]

Comment: Yes, the issue was solved just by turning on the interface "translation" feature. And  "auto save preferences" is enabled in 2.8. Thanks.